# List bullet problems in latex

Tags: latex

I want the effect:

> Stage 1 xxxx
>   Stage 2 xxxx
>   Stage 3 xxxx

but the latex setting code

```
\begin{enumerate}[Stage 1]
```

produces

> Stage 1 xxxx
>   Stbge 2 xxxx
>   Stcge 3 xxxx

Obviously latex take the character 'a' in stage as bullet starter. So how to set static characters in the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to hide the non-enumerable content from [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate). There are a number of ways to achieve this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

% Default enumeration
\begin{enumerate}[Stage 1]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Last
\end{enumerate}

% Hide non-enumerable content using {braces}
\begin{enumerate}[{Stage} 1]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Last
\end{enumerate}

% Hide non-enumerable content using macros
\newcommand{\enumprefix}{Stage}
\begin{enumerate}[\enumprefix{} 1]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Last
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) provides a more explicit way of identifying the enumeration:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={Stage \arabic*}]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Last
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```